# How does cyanogenmod get access to the modem and camera binaries, when Sony's AOSP does not?

Tags: android-source, cyanogenmod

When building Cyanogenmod from source, it seems that all features are working (Modem / Camera/ etc).

But when following official instructions on Sony's website:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/open-source/open-devices/aosp-build-instructions/how-to-build-aosp-lollipop-for-unlocked-xperia-devices/

It seems that the modem and camera are disabled ? Why ? Is it possible to follow some steps from building Cyanogenmod, and some from Sony, to build pure AOSP but also have the modem and camera working ? I don't wan't cyanogenmod, I just want aosp